# Prove that sum of angle inside Triangle is 180

Tags: geometry

How can we prove this question in different way

sum of angle in Triangle is 180

Can we use linear pair ?
Trigonometry ?

Anything?

Comment: passing through a vertex, draw a parallel line to the opposite edge. then show the line is divided into three angles, which are equal to the angles of the triangle

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_postulate

Comment: Walking around the perimeter of a triangle (or any shape) is a full rotation.  Each inner angle is a half rotation minus the turn.  So the sum of the inner angles is 3 half rotation minus a full rotation.

Comment: "different" from what, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw circumcircle of triangle ABC , we have:

$\hat A=\frac 12 \overset{\frown} {BC}$

$\hat B=\frac 12 \overset{\frown} {AC}$

$\hat C=\frac 12 \overset{\frown }{AB}$

Sum them up:

$\hat A+\hat B +\hat C=\frac 12\big(\overset {\frown} {BC}+\overset{\frown}{AC}+\overset{\frown} {AB}\big)=\frac {360}2=180^o$

Comment: Is proving that all triangles have circumcircles easier than proving the angle sum theorem?